# TinyMCE 4.0b3 does not work on localhost on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, tinymce, localhost

I am trying to use tinymce (4.0b3) and tinymce.js has below lines of code which cause an exception. (line: 27888)

```
if (window.localStorage) {
    return localStorage;
}
```

When I request my html page (http ://localhost/editor.html) from localhost using Firefox I get an exception telling: **SecurityError: the operation is insecure.** It works fine for IE and Chrome.

When I deploy page on my website and request page like (http ://www.mydomain.com/editor.html) It works fine for all these three browsers Firefox, IE and Chrome

What may be the cause of SecurityError given by Firefox on localhost? May it be a bug caused by beta version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox SecurityError: "The operation is insecure."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042340/firefox-securityerror-the-operation-is-insecure)