# Firefox SecurityError: "The operation is insecure."

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, backbone.js, cors

I am using [Backbone.LocalStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) plugin with backbone app. It is working fine in chrome and safari however, it is giving me below error in firefox.

> DOMException [SecurityError: "The operation is insecure."
>   code: 18
>   nsresult: 0x80530012
>   location: http://localhost:8000/js/libs/backbone.localStorage/backbone.localStorage.js?version=1453910702146:137]

I am using python `simpleHttpServer`

How can I resolve this error?

**UPDATE**

Here is my code.

```
paths: {
    'jquery'        : 'libs/jquery/dist/jquery',
    'underscore'    : 'libs/underscore/underscore',
    'backbone'      : 'libs/backbone/backbone',
    'localStorage'  : 'libs/backbone.localStorage/backbone.localStorage',
    'text'          : 'plugins/text'
}
```

Here is collection where localStorage is used.

```
var Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: SomeModel,

    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('items'),
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

I am using firefox 36.

**UPDATE 3**

It seems like it is a CORS issue but my firefox version is 36. Which should be fine.

**UPDATE 4**

I am also getting this error in firefox nightly version 44. I also updated my firefox to version 44. Still same error.

Comment: Hope you are using firefox 29. then its a firefox bug

Comment: I am using firefox 36.

Comment: Firefox 58 here and still I'm dealing with such error

Comment: Also with Firefox 60 ... :(

Comment: FF 61.0.2 here and trying to figure this out, when it works in Chrome and Edge.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure Firefox has cookies enabled. 
The setting can be found under Menu/Options/Privacy/History

In the dropdown, select either 'Remember History' or if You prefer use custom settings for history, but select option Accept cookies from sites

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

This happens when we try to access a resource (CSS...) that is located on a different domain. To deal with this error we can use this:

```
                   try {
                     //your critical access to ressources !
                     //rules = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules;
                        } catch(e) {
                   if(e.name !== "SecurityError") {
                       throw e;
                       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your domains are same. verify [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which means same domain, subdomain, protocol (http vs https) and same port.

[What is Same Origin Policy?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)
[How does pushState protect against potential content forgeries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193983/how-does-pushstate-protect-against-potential-content-forgeries)

Comment: I know it is the problem of Same Origin Policy however, I am not sure how can I resolve this? I also don't see why this occurs because I am not sending any request to another domain. All resources are in same domain i.e. localhost in this case.

Comment: place your code snippet in your question to proceed further

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with one script, I dig into error and found it required SSL websockets, so I started SSL and again checked, and It worked.
Try enabling HTTPS and access website as https://127.0.0.1/ It may solve error.