# Firefox Mobile SecurityError for FileReader API

Tags: javascript, firefox, filereader

So my question is somewhat related to [Firefox SecurityError: "The operation is insecure."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042340/firefox-securityerror-the-operation-is-insecure). 
Uploading image works on all browsers expect Firefox Android App, It throws SecurityError. I am not able to understand how this is CORS issue. The image is just read from the FileReader and displayed in the UI.

```
reader.onload = (e) => {
    this.displayImage(e.target.result, file.name);
    this.toggleUploadInput();
  };
  reader.onerror = (e) => {
    alert('error:'+ e.target.error.name);
  };
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Solved, the Firefox didn't have the total access to the camera, mic .. You must make sure that it has access to all your device's resources that it is asking for.

Comment: It actually can access the gallery, camera. So, I am guessing it's not related to asking permissions. Only the image is not sent back to FileReader

Comment: Can you tell me what's your Android version ? When I said all the access I mean all the access, camera, mic, gallery, gps .. Anything it is asking for, this is the thing that I did to fix the same problem (when the fileReader have this security issues)

Comment: My android version is 6.0.1 . How did you solve the problem? Is there any way to ask permission implicitly (by prompting, not through settings)?

Comment: No, I don't think that there is a way to ask the permission in your web app, but as I said you can manage that in the application's manager in your android settings and that's what I did to solve this problem.

Comment: To be exact, the permission we needed is for **Storage**. By default, firefox doesn't ask permission to access storage. If we try to download a file, it will ask for permission. After that its working fine.

Answer (score -2):

I gust go in the Firefox permissions and see this
[android screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYgRc.jpg)

Then I turn on memory access and my script start work nice. As I remember I give all access to Firefox, but don't know why it's don't turn on(